# IronPython "from ... import *" in C#

Tags: ironpython

How do I import types into my hosted IronPython scope from the outside? I could do "from Abc import *" in my script but I need to always import some types and to avoid forgetting to import them I'd like to import them sort of hardcoded/automatically by the host.

I've already done that:

```
strategyScriptEngine.Runtime.LoadAssembly(typeof(Team).Assembly);
```

And I've already tried this to no avail:

```
strategyScriptEngine.Execute(String.Format("from {0} import *", typeof(Team).Namespace));
```

Comment: Assuming that the class Team is located in a namespace and assembly of the same name (e.g. "ClassLibrary") your solution works for me. Could you specify what happens? Which exceptions?

Comment: It seems that for some reason I haven't figured out yet my scope was kind of reinitialized at some place after the mentioned Execute(...). I've put that Execute(...) closer to the actual script execution and now it's working like a charm. I guess I won't go deeper into this in the near future due to a lack of time. Thanks anyway, I appreciate your attempt to help!